# setting correct size for android screen

Tags: android, android-manifest

Pleas can some one help me understand what values I should use to fit most android screen sizes.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

        <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            package="com.airrocketapps.macuser.airrocketapps">



        <supports-screens 
            android:resizeable="true"
            android:smallScreens="true"
            android:normalScreens="true"
            android:largeScreens="true"
            android:xlargeScreens="true"
            android:anyDensity="true"
            android:requiresSmallestWidthDp="320dp"
            android:compatibleWidthLimitDp="320dp"
            android:largestWidthLimitDp="320dp"/>
           <application
```

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/index.html read all the 3 topics

Answer (score 1):

Please have look at this article [Android Layouts for different Screens](https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes.html)

you have to made layout for every screen sizes if you want to handle all types of screen i,e landscape,potrait etc. You must use `wrap_content` or `match_parent` for views to fit into present screen or activity.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't specify it will "support", as in launch on, any device with which the rest of the config is compatible. You can remove the `support-screens` tag completely. But there's a big difference between your layouts _fitting) on screen and them being *appropriately designed* for those screens.

Checkout [Supporting Multiple Screens](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html), [Supporting Different Screen Sizes](https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes.html), and [Designing for Multiple Screens](https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/index.html) in the Android docs.